# css responsive not responsive

Tags: css

why the responsive does not work?
I did various tests but at this point I give up

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row:: after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)  {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you explain what problem you are facing? In addition, there is a typo mistake in your `css` where it says `.row:: after` but it should be `.row::after`. remove space before `after`

Comment: you are re-writting Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing viewport meta tag in html page header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```